# PostgreSQL : Exception handling for key violation

Tags: postgresql

I have the following function to insert the record in the table tbl1.

Table tbl1 has only 1 column with the name cola which is primary key.

Now i want to insert the record using the following function and want to handle if the
key violation error occured. If error occurred then return 0 else return 1.

## My Try:

**Function**: fun1

```
create or replace function fun1
(
value1 int
)
returns integer as

$body$

begin

    insert into tbl1 values(value1);

    return 1; /*Return 1 if inserted */

    exception 
    return 0; /*Return 0 if failed to insert*/

end;

$body$

language plpgsql;
```

**Getting an error**: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "return"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exception block must have at least one condition.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

```
create or replace function fun1(value1 int) returns integer as $body$
begin
    insert into tbl1 values(value1);
    return 1;
exception
    when unique_violation then
        return 0;
end;
$body$ language plpgsql;
```